# PhpSpreadsheet chunk filter read returning empty rows

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to read an XLSX file by chunks. But some of the chunks are empty on the `var_dump` out put.
I'm using PHP7.2 and Laravel 5.5 framework.

That is what I've tried so far:

### Filter

```
class ChunkReadFilter implements IReadFilter
{
private $startRow = 0;
private $endRow   = 0;

// Set the list of rows that we want to read  
public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) {
    $this->startRow = $startRow;
    $this->endRow   = $startRow + $chunkSize;
}

public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
    //  Only read the heading row, and the configured rows
  // if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->startRow && $row < $this->endRow)) {
 if (($row >= $this->startRow && $row < $this->endRow)) {
        if (in_array($column, range('A', 'L'))) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

### Code

```
$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = $path;

$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$chunkSize = 100;
$chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilter();
for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= 800; $startRow += $chunkSize) {

     //Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
    //Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter 
    $reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
    //Load only the rows that match our filter  
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    //Do some processing here
    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
   ->toArray(null, true, true, true);

      var_dump($sheetData);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHPSpreadsheet chuck reader return only current page values and rest on NULL,

Please check following code which can solve your problem.

```
$startRow       = 1;
$arrStrHeadings = [];
$chunkFilter    = new ChunkReadFilter();
$objCsvReader   = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();

$objCsvReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objCsvReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

while (true) {

    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, self::CHUNK_LIMIT);

    $objWorksheet = $objCsvReader->load($arrMixSource['file'])->getActiveSheet();

    $pRange = 'A' . $startRow . ':' . $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn() . $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

    $arrStrSheetData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray( $pRange, $nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = true, $formatData = true, $returnCellRef = false);

    if (0 == count($arrStrSheetData)) {
        break;
    }

    if( 1 == $startRow && empty($arrStrHeadings)) {
        $arrStrHeadings = array_map('strtolower', array_shift($arrStrSheetData));
    }

    foreach ($arrStrSheetData as $arrStrSheetDatum) {

        $arrStrSheetDatum = array_combine($arrStrHeadings, $arrStrSheetDatum);

        // Do oprations...
    }

    $startRow += self::CHUNK_LIMIT;
}
```